# Portfolio Reports from Microsoft Project files

Tags: ms-project, reporting, visualization

How can I take schedule information from multiple (40+) Microsoft Project files and create portfolio dashboards and reports. Specifically, I'd like to see Gantt charts for all projects in a stack.

Comment: The FAQ specifically states that you should not ask questions for tool recommendations; that tends to generate negative comments which diminish the value of the site.  Suggest that you may wish to rewrite the question to elicit requirements, or best practices, etc.  *How do I consolidate, aggregate and summarize information from multiple projects?*

Comment: Agreed. It is definitely okay to ask for solutions or how to evaluate a tool for a particular use, but we find asking for tool lists tend to attract spam. Plus, you can find tools in the [tag:pm-software] tag. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Since this hasn't been closed yet I'll try and answer based on the limited information.

There are two ways you can do this.  You can get a Project Server setup to manage this information for you, and even go as far as to have a Sharepoint Server pull this information and display KPI's and all the pretty bells-and-whistles on a Sharepoint Site.

If Project Server and Sharepoint Server are out of your reach, you can do this manually by making a Master Project within Microsoft Project.  Once the Master Project has been created, point yourself to the "Project" tab and subproject out all the projects you want to fall into the Master Project for a dashboard view.  Make sure that the projects are linked content-wise.  As long as you do not change the location of the project or files once these have been subbed-out - you can edit and manage all of your projects from the Master Project and it will update and save the subprojects for you.

**Here's a Quick Tutorial**: http://www.kodyaz.com/microsoft-office/create-master-project-subproject-microsoft-project-2010.aspx